# signature not found in user keyring, perhaps try the interactive 'ecryptfs-mount-private'

Tags: 13.04, login, encryption, users, ecryptfs

My Ubuntu 13.04 froze while working with the encrypted user account USER1 . I rebooted and since then I cant login to the user account USER1 even with correct password.

I login in to user account USER2 to get access to TTY and login to user account USER1 and i get the following error :

```
Signature not found in user keyring
Perhaps try the interactive 'ecryptfs-mount-private'

ecryptfs-mount-private
Enter your login passphrase:
Inserted auth tok with sig [xxxxxxxxxx] into the user session keyring

INFO: Your private directory has been mounted
INFO: To see this change in your current shell: User Home path
```

I then login to the user account USER1 from the greeter login page. I always have to follow this procedure to login to the user account USER1.

Is there a way to insert the user keyring permanently ?

Comment: did you find any solution for for this?